# Is there a term for when you complain about something, and then it just starts working right?

Tags: obscure-terms

I often find that when working with different forms of technology it breaks then when you have someone watch it or complain to someone it works. Is there a term for this?

Comment: The program crashes when I do [something]. Let me show you. Program does not crash. But, "It worked before"!

Answer (score 1):

There's **[heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)**, a pun on physicist [Werner Heisenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_Heisenberg) and the [observer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics)), a phenomenon whereby observing a system causes its behaviour to change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an existing name, but I'll make one up:

**Cheshire cat bug**

This comes from Lewis Caroll's character, the Cheshire cat, who disappeared and reappeared from time to time.